# RecyclerView does not enter under tabLayout and toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I made the Toolbar and TabLayout transparent. In TabLayout, I have two fragments with RecyclerView. 
When I scroll, the contents of the recyclerView do not go under the tolbar. Please tell me how to fix. 
 I use the behaviour but it seems not working

app_bar_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
      android:background="@color/transparent"  />

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView ..... />
        <TextView ..... />

      </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton ..../>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragment.PoemFragment">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPoem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="88dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this behavior in root of that view that want to place below of `AppBarLayout`, not in child of views (Fragments)

just add this behavior to `ViewPager`

just change :

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
      android:background="@color/transparent"  />
```

to :

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
      android:background="@color/transparent" 
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: it works for me :)  in your case it does not fix in preview too?